# method missing or method undefined `upsert' for #<mark:0x000055d9d09442d8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upsert

I'm seeding a DB from a TXT file which will need updated from time to time, and wanted to try the new upsert function.

HOWEVER having pulled a 4am I'm almost not able to read the screen and think I'm doing something obvious or stupid, woods for trees stuff?

I've re-read the documentation and updated the rails version but when I call the upsert on an object I get an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `upsert' for #<Trademark:0x000055a4c3234bd8>
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activemodel-6.1.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:469:in `method_missing'
```

I have updated RAILS to 6.1.2. Ruby is at 2.7.0 and the DB is PG 1.2.3

Column  :mark_number is has a unique index in the DB on it.

here is my seed code, I'm following documentation.

l object is the uploaded txt file which I step through line by line and split into an array.

```
t = mark.new
t.mark_hyperlink = l[1].split('"')[1].strip
t.mark_number=l[0].strip
puts t.mark_number
# Create bitstring of 45 classes
bitstring=""
 (12..56).each do |i|
  bitstring=bitstring + l[i]
 end
puts bitstring
t.class_bitstring=bitstring

# also tried inserting like this, comes back with fail
#upsert(t, returning: nil, unique_by: :mark_number)

t.upsert
```

Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a class method, not instance method. Should look like this:

```
Trademark.upsert(attributes)
```